# Why disallow some review queues when daily vote max is reached?

Tags: discussion, voting, reviewing

So I discovered, after a premeditated session of voting (I've been stocking up a bunch of up|down vote-worthy posts to earn my Vox Populi badge while voting ethically), that once a user's daily vote limit has been reached, then they become disqualified from reviewing First Posts and Late Answers.

Do you think that this is an odd restriction?

I mean, I merely have to wait for 24 hours, but voting isn't the only way to review these types of posts.   Preventing me from voting further is perfectly acceptable, but I can still contribute effectively as a reviewer without voting.

Thoughts?

Comment: ...couldn't add `reviewing` tag

Comment: I haven't looked into the meta topics about this as I've been awya for the last couple of days. But for now, I can only assume it's like this so that it gives other members the chance to contribute/moderate too.